# how to create a RF drive test tool

Tags: android, iphone, network-programming, gsm, cellular-network

My boss just told me our next project and my job is to create a simple RF Drive Test tool... The best part about this project is that I finally found a question google has no answer to "how to create a RF drive test tool" ....

Can anyone please guide me how to approach this.... I'm completely confused at how I would even try to access GSM data let alone try to break it and read whats inside the packets...

Any help... Any advice.... Anything at all, will be greatly appreciated... if you know anything about this topic please let me know....

thanks

Comment: In order to create a proper drive test application, you would need to purchase documentation from the modem manufacturer, which can cost >$1M

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to build a tool that just gets some information about the network strength and network quality.  You need a GSM modem attached to a computer, and an interface over which you can get information from the modem.

As an interface, you could use [AT commands](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm), or a proprietary API, like the Qualcomm Gobi one.  It depends which modem you use, and what chipset it's based on.
Android Telephony interface also gives some signal strength/quality information, but not all modems support all functions of this interface.
Windows Mobile Broadband API probably doesn't give you enough information.

The more complicated alternative, would be to build the modem firmware yourself, which would give you the option to intercept information coming directly from the GSM network.  Test equipment manufacturers have whole teams working on that. From what you describe, that is beyond the scope of your task.